# Map multiple words to single word in Lucene SynonymGraphFilter

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using lucene 6.4.0. When I map **dns** to **domain name system**, I can get the correct query.
But when I try to map **domain name system** to **dns**, I can't get the correct query. I set **parser.setSplitOnWhitespace(false)**.

```
public class SynonymAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s, Reader reader) {
        SynonymMap synonymMap = null;
        SynonymMap.Builder builder=null;
        try {
            addTo(builder,new String[]{"dns"},new String[]{"domain\u0000name\u0000system"});
            addTo(builder,new String[]{"domain\u0000name\u0000system"},new String[]{"dns"});
            synonymMap = builder.build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream filter = new SynonymGraphFilter(tokenizer, synonymMap, true);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }

     private void addTo(SynonymMap.Builder builder, String[] from, String[] to) {
         for (String input : from) {
             for (String output : to) {
                 builder.add(new CharsRef(input), new CharsRef(output), false);
             }
         }
     }
}


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String queryStr="domain name system";
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("n",SynonymAnalyzer);
        parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
        parser.setSplitOnWhitespace(false);
        Query query=parser.parse(queryStr);
}
```